# groovy: convert string (which is a list) to a Groovy List

Tags: grails, groovy

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def ver = "['a', 'b', 'c']"
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def ver_list = jsonSlurper.parseText(ver)
println ver_list
```

This is what I'm doing. I want to iterate over `ver_list`. And it seems difficult to find a solution for it.

This is the error when I print ver_list:

```
Caught: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

The current character read is ''' with an int value of 39
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
line number 1
index number 1
['a', 'b', 'c']
.^
groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

The current character read is ''' with an int value of 39
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
line number 1
index number 1
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. A string isn't a list, it's a text representation of a list. What's the issue after you parse it as JSON? You print it, I don't see any attempt to iterate or anything.

Comment: Ah, I didn't write it properly. Let me edit the question.

Comment: the valid json strings should be double-quoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the valid json strings must be double-quoted.

so change in your code this line and it should work:

```
def ver = '["a", "b", "c"]'
```

however if you need to parse not a valid json you could try LAX parser.

then even the following string could be parsed

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonParserType

def ver = "[a, 'b', 001]"
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().setType( JsonParserType.LAX )
def ver_list = jsonSlurper.parseText(ver)
println ver_list
```